# angularjs ng-repeat item is undefined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to show each item in cList on, but it isn't working. It creates the correct number of div tags (from ng-repeat), but they are empty. It seems like item is undefined, so nothing shows up.

This is the controller:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp');

app.controller('listController', function($scope) {
  $scope.cList = [ 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5' ];
});
```

This is the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="listController">
  <div ng-repeat="item in cList">
    {{item}}
  </div>
</div>
```

It produces this HTML repeated 5 times:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in cList" class="ng-scope">

</div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: item in cList -->
```

If I put something else in the div tag in the ng-repeat, that will show up on the page 5 times. Is there any reason that item would be undefined?

Comment: did you check the answer?

Comment: @sajeetharan it didn't fix the problem. Could it be an issue with the way the project is set up?

Comment: can you give me team viewer?

Answer (score 1):

Add empty dependency array to your module,

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

 <body ng-app='myApp'  >
   <div ng-controller="listController">
     <div ng-repeat="item in cList">
       {{item}}
    </div>
     </div>
  </body>
```

[WORKING DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/FFjoTen5fZhptNfaV0wq?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the below code

```
     var app = angular.module('MyApp');
```

with this

```
    var app = angular.module('MyApp',[]);
```